# Accessing ItemsControl.Items from ItemsControl.DataTemplate

Tags: c#, silverlight

Is it possible to somehow pass the collection of `ItemsControl.Items` to each individual item in the control via bindings?

What I want to do would look like this (the WorkspaceCubes binding specifically): (it doesn't currently work because you can't bind to an `ItemsControl` or its `Items`)

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="workspace" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CubeViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas Background="SkyBlue" Margin="0"></Canvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Canvas>
                <Sift:CubeView WorkspaceCubes="{Binding ElementName=workspace, Path=Items}"  DataContext="{Binding}"></Sift:CubeView>
            </Canvas>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your purposes, but you can try with:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="workspace" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CubeViewModels}" DataContext="{Binding Path=CubeViewModels}"> 
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
        <ItemsPanelTemplate> 
            <Canvas Background="SkyBlue" Margin="0"></Canvas> 
        </ItemsPanelTemplate> 
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel> 
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate> 
            <Canvas> 
                <Sift:CubeView WorkspaceCubes="{Binding}"></Sift:CubeView> 
            </Canvas> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
</ItemsControl>
```